# SystemVerilog Enumerated Multi-Domain Array -> how to declare/define?

Tags: system-verilog

Here is an example how to define the 2*N array of enum types of {S0,S1,S2,S3}:

**typedef** **enum** logic [N-1:0][1:0]{S0,S1,S2,S3} state_t;  (*)

So, each element of the above 2*N array could be either S0 or S1 or S2 or S3.

Let's say the {S0,S1,S2,S3} are defined as a separate **enum** type:

**typedef enum** {S0,S1,S2,S3} st_t;

So how now could I rewrite the first statement (*)?

Could it be re-written as the following:

typedef enum st_t [N-1:0][1:0] state_t;

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge `typedef enum logic [N-1:0][1:0]{S0,S1,S2,S3} state_t;` should not compile, and I was not able to get it to compile on any simulator on [EDAplayground](https://www.edaplayground.com/). Enums need a simple vector datatype. `logic [N-1:0][1:0]` is a double packed array and thereby isn't simple.

If you do not specify the data type of an enum, it is assumed to be an `int`.

`typedef enum st_t [N-1:0][1:0] state_t;` has a similar problem as your original statement, but now you define an enum as an double packed enums. Plus you never define the enum values.

What will work:

```
typedef enum logic [1:0] {S0,S1,S2,S3} st_t;
typedef st_t [N-1:0] state_t;
```

Or as an unpacked array:

```
typedef enum logic [1:0] {S0,S1,S2,S3} st_t;
typedef st_t state_t [N];
```

---

Read more about user-defined types (`typedef`) and enumerations (`enum`) in [IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § 6.18 *User-defined types* and § 6.19 *Enumerations*

Try differnet combinations on your SystemVerilog simulator or a one of the many simulators on [EDA Playground](https://www.edaplayground.com) (Use one of the commercial simulators, the free ones have limit if any SV featurs)

Comment: Cannot I define the {S0,S1,S2,S3} as a separate type? Something like that:

`typedef enum {S0,S1,S2,S3} ss_t;
typedef enum logic [1:0][ss_t] st_t;
typedef st_t state_t [N];`

Comment: You cannot define an enum with another enum. An enum’s datatype must be a simple vector type (ex `int`, `logic [7:0]`, `byte`, `bit [23:0]`, etc). If a datatype is not specified then `int` is assumed. `typedef` cannot be treated as macros.

Comment: Could the above be re-written as following (using `define for substitution): 
(tick)define ss_t {S0,S1,S2,S3};
typedef enum logic [1:0] (tick)ss_t st_t;
typedef st_t state_t [N];
As far as I understand, this is a 3-D array, correct?

Comment: No, it is a 2-D array. `{S0,S1,S2,S3}` is the legal content of the enum, it does not determine the bit-width. The `logic [1:0]` specifies the bit-width, bit-state type (eg: bit vs logic), and if it signed/unsigned. `enum logic [1:0] {S0,S1,S2,S3}` is an 2-bit unsigned enum where `S0=2'b00, S1=2'b01, S2=2'b10, S3=2'b11`. In contrast `enum {S0,S1,S2,S3}` is a 32-bit signed enum where `S0=32'd0, S1=32'd1, S2=32'd2, S3=32'd3` (there is zero padding)

Comment: Greg, thanks a lot for your explanations. Anyway, could the above code be re-written as following:  (using `define for substitution): (tick)define ss_t {S0,S1,S2,S3}; typedef enum logic [1:0] (tick)ss_t st_t; typedef st_t state_t [N]; ?

Comment: I've update my answer with links to documentation and an online simulator to try things out on your own.